# zsh: event not found: /bin/bash

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, zsh

When I  run the following on my command line `#!/bin/bash`  I get the error `zsh: event not found: /bin/bash`.

I'm on Mac Ventura.

If I run `zsh` the command works fine, so the issue is with `/bin/bash`.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: The `!` character is used in zsh for history expansion. Read the `HISTORY EXPANSION` section of `man zshexpn` to learn more. In any case, running `#!/bin/bash` as a command would not do anything, this is useful only in scripts, where the first line starting with a shebang (`#!`) has special meaning and indicates the (usually shell) executable to use to run the script.

Comment: Shebang (#!) is used as the first line of a shell script. It's an instruction to the system "Run this script using this shell". It's not a command to be used on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation

`#!/bin/bash` is a common shebang. To be a shebang, this line has to be the first line of a script.

A shebang in a script matters for the kernel when you start the script as an executable. The shebang tells the kernel which interpreter to start. The path to the script is passed to the interpreter.

The interpreter itself (`/bin/bash` in this case) should ignore the shebang. In many interpreters (including `bash`) this requires no special treatment, because in many languages `#` starts a comment anyway; from the point of view of the interpreter the shebang is just a comment.

If the shebang in a script was `#!/bin/zsh` and you directly run the script as an executable (e.g. `/path/to/the-script` or `./the-script`), or if you explicitly invoked `zsh` to interpret a script with any shebang (e.g. `zsh ./the-script`) then `zsh` would run non-interactively and it would interpret the shebang as a comment. This is fine; when the interpreter gets to the shebang, the shebang has already served its purpose and can (or rather: should) safely be ignored.

It looks like you pasted `#!/bin/bash` into an *interactive* `zsh`. Interactive `zsh` by default does not treat `#comments` as comments like other shells, [you need to run `setopt interactive_comments` to enable the feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557490/108618). Your `zsh` tried to interpret `#!/bin/bash` as a command. Then history expansion kicked in because of the `!`. This is why you got `zsh: event not found: /bin/bash`.

`setopt interactive_comments` is not a solution in this case. If the code you want to paste starts with `#!/bin/bash` then it's a clear indication the code is for `bash`, not for `zsh`. You shall not mindlessly feed it to any `zsh`, interactive or not.

---

#### Solution

Save the whole snippet starting with `#!/bin/bash` to a regular file, make the file executable (with `chmod +x`) and execute it. The mechanics of shebang will do its job and `bash` will be started to interpret the code intended for `bash`. This is the right way to run such snippets.

---

#### Broader view

In general, if you want to run a snippet by pasting it to an interactive interpreter, then you need to do the shebang-related job of the kernel by yourself: you need to pay attention to the shebang and choose the right interpreter. In your case you could paste the snippet to an interactive bash and it would *probably* work.

"Probably", not "certainly", because interactive and non-interactive shells of the same type are somewhat different anyway. E.g. if the shebang was `#!/bin/zsh`, the right interpreter would be `zsh`, but the code wouldn't run smoothly after being pasted to an interactive `zsh` because of `interactive_comments` disabled. In such case `setopt interactive_comments` might help. There are more differences that may result in an interactive shell doing things the author of code did not intend.

In general the right way to run code that starts with a shebang is to save it in a regular file, make the file executable and invoke it. *In some cases* you can get away with pasting to an interactive interpreter, if you choose the interpreter according to the shebang (or at least compatible with the one specified in the shebang). But even if the shell is right, pasting a multi-line snippet to an interactive shell may in itself be problematic (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/606657/108618)), this is why a feature called "bracketed paste" is useful for interactive shells.

---

#### Observation, personal view

Short snippets of shell code published here on Super User are usually safe when being pasted into the right shell. It may be such snippet includes a shebang only to indicate the right shell. I tend to explicitly warn in my answers if my code certainly should not be pasted interactively. Still, if a snippet includes a shebang then it's usually best to create a script (file) instead of pasting interactively.

At least once ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716244/108618)) I used a line that resembles a shebang but cannot work as one. It was only to indicate the right shell.